# mysql search for segment of table name

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to select tables in a mysql database which have the same ending, e.g. staff_name, manager_name, customer_name (example). 
I was thinking of something along the lines of the following because it works if I have a definite table name.

```
SELECT * FROM "%_name";
```

I also tried this using a % instead of the _ with no luck. I'm not sure if there are other wildcards I could try. I've looked around, but none of the results seem to apply to parts of table names :/ Any suggestions?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%_name'
and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db_name'
```

If you want to search for tables in your current DB you can do

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE '%_name'
```

Comment: You can also do `SHOW TABLES LIKE "%_name"`, which is slightly shorter.

Comment: Woo! Works like a charm, muchos gracias amigo! :D

Comment: @Schuller that is even better thanks! It is related to the database I'm in and is quicker :) :)

Comment: @MichaelCSchuller: Thanks. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to show the tables and their contents? 
They all have the same column names so I want to query a particular column's contents. 
E.g. I want all the tables with ending '%_name' which in turn do not have performance 1 in the 'performance' column.

Comment: It is not possible to combile a select of tables names with the content of the table. It is probably possible with dynamic sql. But that is a whole other question.

Comment: ahh ok, that's a bit of a bummer as I have around 4,400 tables that match my table name query ;(. guess I'm gonna have to go old school and troll through them all.

Comment: You could ask another question specifically about this. Maybe someone else has a clue.

Comment: Oh, apparently you can also do `SHOW TABLES LIKE '%_name' IN <Database>` as well, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 4):

> you can do in 3 way

```
show tables like '%yourtablename'
show tables like '%yourtablename%'

show tables like 'yourtablename%'
```