# Query a database with results from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql

There are some similar questions around but they aren't quite what I'm looking for, so forgive me if you think this is answered elsewhere.

I am basically looking for an easy way to do things as I have over 4000 tables to get data from. This kind of follows on from my previous post: [mysql search for segment of table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931961/mysql-search-for-segment-of-table-name)

The general situation is that I have a database filled with tables and I only want about a quarter of this which comes to around 4000 tables. I have a list of the individual table names thanks to my previous post, but I want the data that goes with them. 
I know that for an individual one I can do SELECT table1.*, table2.*; or something similar but I don't want to go through all 4000 or so. 
They all end with the same thing, e.g. staff_name, manager_name, customer_name so I can use

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE '%_name'
```

to see the table names that I want in the database. Someone suggested using dynamic mysql, but I don't even know where to start with that. Any suggestions?

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675669/searching-for-a-specific-id-in-a-large-database)

Comment: @juergend what does [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675669/searching-for-a-specific-id-in-a-large-database) have to do with the question?

Comment: @MihaiStancu: In the accepted answer is a script that searches for specific columns and content.

Comment: But it's for SQL-Server with lots of SQL-Server specific syntax. @bladepanthera would have little luck in porting that himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Generic example (in PHP):

Constructing dynamic SQL or building your SQL queries with the aid of a programming language would look like this (in PHP for ex.):

```
$pdos = $pdo->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '%_name'");
$tables = $pdos->fetchAll();

$query = 'SELECT * FROM '.implode(' UNION SELECT * FROM ');
$pdo->query($query);
```

The `fetchAll` method will return an array containing the names of each table selected.

The `implode($glue, $array)` function takes an array and concatenates every value in the array using the `$glue` parameter - usually you take an array of values and implode them using `$glue = ','` to create a coma separated list of values.

In our case the `implode` has a partial query as `$glue` in order to create one big `UNION JOIN` query.

Once the final `$query` is build it should look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1_name
    UNION
SELECT * FROM table_2_name
    UNION
SELECT * FROM table_3_name
    ....
    ....
    UNION
SELECT * FROM table_4000_name
```

The result should contain all of the `DISTINCT` rows from all 4000 tables.

### Specific example (in SQL-only format):

```
SELECT    GROUP_CONCAT(
              CONCAT('select * from ', table_name)
              SEPARATOR ' union '
          )
    INTO  @my_variable
    FROM  information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'dbname'
    AND   table_name LIKE '%_name';

PREPARE   my_statement FROM @my_variable;
EXECUTE   my_statement;
```

- The first statement will get all of the table names from the `information_schema` database;
- The `CONCAT` function prefixes every table name with a a `'SELECT * FROM '` string;
- The `GROUP_CONCAT` does the job that `implode` would have done in PHP;
- The `INTO` clause makes sure the values are saved inside a variable named `my_variable`;
- The `PREPARE` statement takes a string value (such as the one you saved in `my_variable`) and checks if the value is an SQL query;
- The `EXECUTE` statement takes a "prepared statement" and well... executes it.

@my_variable is a temporary variable but it can only be of a scalar type (varchar, int, date, datetime, binary, float, double etc.) it is **not** an array.

The `GROUP_CONCAT` function is an "aggregate function" which means it takes an aggregate value (similar concept to an array - in our case the result set of our query) and outputs a simple string result.

Comment: hmmm that looks really useful... forgiving my ignorance, but can it be used in phpmyAdmin?

Comment: nope, PHPMyAdmin is an application written in PHP, it does not allow you to run PHP code directly in it. But if you have FTP access to the server where your PHPMyAdmin is installed then you can upload a PHP file of your own. The PHP file will have to specify a bit more info such as SQL connection credentials (user/pass).

Comment: Since you obviously want to do this in SQL only and not use an external language, I'll update my code.

Comment: Bang! The query is dynamically generated prepared and executed using only SQL queries.

Comment: That looks fantastic! So the @my_variable is like a temporary variable that can be used as an array of data or something like that? 
I've never seen the prepare & execute statements before, interesting.
`PREPARE my_statement FROM @my_variable` comes up with a Table 'table_name.aaaa_name' doesn't exist error

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain more about the basic concepts of the SQL variable and group_concat. About the table not existing - I've tested the code in my environment it works for sure, it may be that you do not have a database selected when issuing the `EXECUTE` statement. If you want this to work without having a database selected you have to prefix the table name with `dbname.tablename` in the `CONCAT`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest generating the SQL statement.

Try doing:

```
select concat('select * from ', table_name) as query
from Information_Schema.tables
where table_schema = <dbname> and
      table_name like <whatever>
```

You can then run this as a bunch of queries by copying into a query editor window.

If you want everything as one query, then do:

```
select concat('select * from ', table_name, ' union all ') as query
from Information_Schema.tables
where table_schema = <dbname> and
      table_name like <whatever>
```

And remove the final "union all".

This has the table name matching a like.  Leave out the table_name part of the WHERE to get all tables.  Or, include specific tables using table_name in ().

Comment: An interesting piece of code and it does sort-of-half of what I want, by listing the queries (can't access them tho) - at least it makes it easier to see... 
Is there a way where it says table_name to specify tables like '%_name'?

Comment: btw, it is table_schema not schema_name :)

Comment: This is very good, although not quite what I want as I want to see what is actually in the tables. I can copy all the queries and edit them, though which is a start. Thanks for the help!!