# Mysql dynamic query to fetch all table name like custom

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql - query a database with results from multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935023/mysql-query-a-database-with-results-from-multiple-tables)

Hello Friends I have this query in Sql but ui want to execute in MYSQL.

```
DECLARE @sql AS nvarchar(max)
    set @sql=''
    set @sql='Select * From('
    SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
    SELECT name  FROM ['+ SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) +'].[' + name + ']
    UNION ALL '
    FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T where table_name like 'Custom%'
    SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 0, len(@sql)-9)
    print @sql
```

My requirement is to UNion all tables in database that start with Custom

Please give me solution to execute .
I used this in MYSQL.
but hard to find result.

```
DECLARE @sql AS nvarchar(max)
    set @sql=''
    SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
    SELECT name  FROM ['+ SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) +'].[' + name + ']
    UNION ALL '
    FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T where table_name like 'Custom%'
    SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 0, len(@sql)-9)
    print @sql
```

Comment: @Ariel : "My requirement is to UNion all tables in database that start with Custom"

Comment: @samsamX Next time post the complete question all at once. You are one vote away from having this question closed as not a real question.

Comment: @Ariel please notice I'm not the owner of this question, I just shown you where was the question.

Comment: @samsamX Sorry about that. Also, when I posted my message the question was basically blank. neha prajapati consider this message directed at you.