# Combining multiple MYSQL tables

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL database consisting of 1000 tables which have all been imported from an external source. They are named as follows:

```
    | 1502838000-1502924399_ulog     |
    | 1502838000-1502924399_urls     |
    | 1502924400-1503010799_sessions |
    | 1502924400-1503010799_ulog     |
    | 1502924400-1503010799_urls     |
    | 1503010800-1503062776_sessions |
    | 1503010800-1503062776_ulog     |
    | 1503010800-1503062776_urls     |
    | 1503062777-1503097199_sessions |
    | 1503062777-1503097199_ulog     |
    | 1503062777-1503097199_urls     |
    | 1503097200-1503183599_sessions |
    | 1503097200-1503183599_ulog     |
    | 1503097200-1503183599_urls     |
    | 1503183600-1503269999_sessions |
    | 1503183600-1503269999_ulog     |
    | 1503183600-1503269999_urls     |
```

As you can see there are basically three types of table. Sessions, ulog and urls. What I want to do is to query all tables ending in sessions for firstName and lastName. I want to run similar queries on the other two types too. Ive tried a whole lot of stuff but haven't really got anywhere.

Ive tried combining all of each type into one table so that ultimately id have three tables but have come up flat on that.

Ive also tried querying through them but can't seem to get the query right to cycle through the correct tables.

Can anybody assist please?

Comment: What have you done so far?  Post your query.

Comment: You will need to use dynamic sql (or do it outside of mysql), see e.g. [mysql - query a database with results from multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11935023/6248528). Do yourself a favour and use this to insert all data into a (or three) new, single table(s), and don't keep your data in 1000 seperate tables.

Comment: @eric  Ive tried creating another table which contains the names of all of the original database tables as follows: CREATE TABLE intermediate-table names select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='wifistats'; Ive then tried to execute the following: select emailAd from information_schema.tables, intermediate-table names where table_schema='wifistats' and table_name LIKE '%sessions' INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/emails.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','; Its way off I know but its the closest Ive got so far :|

Comment: That looks interesting @solarflare thanks. I realise now I should've separated these tables before importing them and I guess I still could. Im going to take a look at the PHP method as it looks kinda cool :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest to do would be writing script for PHP-CLI to fit it into one table, it can scan trought tables really fast without getting to know more complicated SQL statements.